# Simple Image Hiding--"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, css, display

This seems really silly, but I've read dozens of similar forum posts and I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm designing a website with a menu button whose icon changes to an "X" when it is open. It toggles on each click. The javascript function runs but returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined" when it reaches the line changing the menu button's style.display to "none".

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<img id="menuIconImage" class="menuIcon" src="resources/menu.png" onclick="menuToggle()">
<img id="menuIconImageClose" class="menuIcon" src="resources/close.png" onclick="menuToggle()">
```

CSS:

```
.menuIcon {

    position: fixed;
    left: 33px;
    top: 178px;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#menuIconImageClose {

    //the "close" image/button is hidden by default.
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var menuState = 0;

function menuToggle() {
    "use strict";

    if (menuState === 0) {

        document.getElementById("menuIconImage").stlye.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("menuIconImageClose").style.display = "block";
        menuState = 1;

    } else if (menuState === 1) {

        document.getElementById("menuIconImageClose").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("menuIconImage").style.display = "block";
        menuState = 0;      
    }
}
```

Comment: where is `menuState` defined?

Comment: It's defined at the top of the script. I just added the definition for your review.

Comment: you just removed 2 lines of code in each of the if statements, make sure those are not giving an error as i don't see the elements that they referred to in your code.

Comment: You misspelled 'style'.  `document.getElementById("menuIconImage").stlye.display = "none"` should be `document.getElementById("menuIconImage").style.display = "none"`

Comment: good eye, Kevin. those lines of code run just fine; it is the following line which returns an error:

Comment: @mrogers has the good eyes here, he spotted the misspelled word

Comment: @mrogers, that is the solution. Can't believe I didn't see that; thank you! How can I mark your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: @DrakeWithers I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a misspelled word 'stlye' which should be 'style' at this line:

`document.getElementById("menuIconImage").stlye.display = "none";`

should be

`document.getElementById("menuIconImage").style.display = "none";`

My analysis to determine the issue started with the text of the error which indicated that the issue wasn't with finding the element (i.e. the `document.getElementById("menuIconImage")` part worked).  If the element wasn't found we'd get an error with text `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`.  This narrowed down where the issue was.

Comment: I appreciate the additional explanation.